# java hashmap basic question

Tags: java

```
HashMap model1 = wordobject.getMap();
Set sample = model1.keySet();
Iterator it = sample.iterator();
```

==
Can you please explain me the above 3 lines?
I see that we are trying to get the hash table from the object and get it assigned to the HashMapmodel1.

1) what is keyset?
2) what does .iterator do?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: Javadocs were invented for a reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are declaring a typical Java HashMap in the first line (a little obvious). You usually construct a HashMap using generics for key value pairs: `HashMap<K,V>`

The Java API HashMap class allows you to get a set of the keys used for the HashMap. The keySet() method returns a `Set<K>`.

An iterator allows you to iterate through the set calling methods like next() and hasNext(). It is a way to traverse the set sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

1. A Hashtable != HashMap
2. The [documentation for `Map#keyset()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet%28%29) says `Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map`
3. The [documentation for `Iterator` in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) - a more general discussion can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator)

Answer (score 0):

the ketSet() is clearly going to return a Set object (hence when we are instantiating the Set object, sample, with it's result). This Set contains all of the Key Values from the HashMap. Its type will be whatever type the Keys in the hasMap were. The iterator provides a way to step through the elements of the set.

oh and as someone pointed out, we are getting a HashMap from wordobject.

Answer (score 0):

An iterator allows you to loop through the `Set`. A `Set` is like an `ArrayList` but does not allow you to index it. Quick google of set or iterator will give you some more info about them both. Here's a link that explains iterators: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=235

Answer (score 0):

1) keySet() is a method on map that returns all the keys for the map. Just to make it clearer, map is like a collection of  pairs. i.e. each item in a map has a key and a value associated with it. Like a english dictionary, where each item in the dictionary is a word (the key) and a corresponding meaning (the value). So, keySet() will return a set of all the keys, i.e. the words in the dictionary.
2).iterator() returns an Iterator for the set. You can use the iterator "it" to iterate through the items in the set by using its methods like "next()", "hasNext()", "remove()".. etc..

Read up a little more Java docs to learn more.